# Allow users to access apache only using url not ip

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I want to allow users to access my apache website using url only. If somebody accesses it using the ip address he should be blocked in some way. Can this be done in apache ?

Comment: What is the problem you're actually trying to solve, why shouldn't people access your site with IP only ?

Comment: My customer has some security requirement to prohibit access using ip.

Answer (score 4):

Configure your apache with Name Based Virtual hosts. The first virtualhost entry is the default, which in your case can be blank,  and the next one(s) the actual virtual host(s) for your domain(s) that will only be reached when the requested host name matches a pre-defined virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                         # OR:
<VirtualHost _default_:80>                 # In Apache 2.2
   # The first VirtualHost is a catch-all  # In Apache 2.4
   ServerName unconfigured.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/unconfigured
</VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   # The next VirtualHost only appears when the correct ServerName or Alias is used
   ServerName www.example.com
   ServerAlias example.com shop.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```